# Swear word filter in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a swear word filter in c#. I am using a string list and going through it and checking if the input contains a word from the list. But when i run the code, it does not filter anything.

I have tried to make it an array change it to a boolean but nothing seems to work.

```cs
private List<string> badWords = new List<string>();
    public string FilterSwear(string text)
    {
        string filterd = text;
        foreach (string badWord in badWords)
        {
            if (text.Contains(badWord))
            {
                int chars = badWord.Length;
                string stars = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < chars; i++)
                {
                    stars += "*";
                }
                filterd.Replace(badWord, stars);
            }
        }

        return filterd;
    }
```

Comment: You never show badWords being populated with anything.

Comment: Side note: the `String` class has a constructor that makes it easy to create a string that consists of a character repreated n-times. No need for that "bulky" `for` loop with `stars+= "*"`. Just do `stars = new string('*', badWord.Length);` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
filterd = filterd.Replace(badWord, stars);
```

Replace doesn't replace in-place - it returns copy with replaced string and leaves original intact.